# convert date from yyyy-mm-dd to day-month-date

Tags: date, blackberry, java-me, date-format

I have date in this format `2011-11-02`. From this date, how can we know the `Day-of-week`, `Month` and `Day-of-month`, like in this format `Wednesday-Nov-02`, from calendar or any other way?

Comment: is it related to java anyway? you did not tag it as such.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If it were normal java, you would use two [SimpleDateFormats](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) - one to read and one to write:

```
SimpleDateFormat read = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
SimpleDateFormat write = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE-MMM-dd");
String str = write.format(read.parse("2011-11-02"));
System.out.println(str);
```

Output:

```
Wednesday-Nov-02
```

As a function (ie static method) it would look like:

```
public static String reformat(String source) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat read = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    SimpleDateFormat write = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE-MMM-dd");
    return write.format(read.parse(source));
}
```

Warning:
Do not be tempted to make `read` or `write` into static fields to save instantiating them every method invocation, because **SimpleDateFormat is not thread safe!**

#### Edited

However, after consulting the [Blackberry Java 5.0 API doc](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/index.html), it seems the `write.format` part should work with blackberry's [SimpleDateFormat](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/i18n/SimpleDateFormat.html), but you'll need to parse the date using something else... [HttpDateParser](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/io/http/HttpDateParser.html) looks promising. I don't have that JDK installed, but try this:

```
public static String reformat(String source) {
    SimpleDateFormat write = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE-MMM-dd");
    Date date = new Date(HttpDateParser.parse(source));
    return write.format(date);
}
```

Comment: @Coder I've edited the answer with a possible blackberry solution

Comment: @Bohemian: +1 "SimpleDateFormat is not thread safe!" - cool catch. Going to review my code. :)